# DHCP in Wirelss LAN Controller

Tags: vlan, wireless, dhcp, cisco-wlc

I want to manage the DHCP of my Wi-Fi traffic from my wireless LAN controller.I don't have a VLAN. It is just that i am using single interface e.g., Management interface.

I have assigned the DHCP pool from the DHCP scope option. I have kept the pool form 192.168.1.100 to 192.168.1.150. But every time I connect to the SSID of the controller, I am not getting an IP address from the pool, but I'm getting an IP address which is not indicated in the pool e.g., 192.168.1.7.

Do I have to specify this scope somewhere in the interface or WLAN? Please help.

Comment: Which device model?

Comment: cisco wlc 2500 series

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The controller just bridges the the Wi-Fi traffic; you get DHCP from a DHCP server, either on the LAN or on a different LAN with the aid of a helper address in the router port for the LAN.

You normally want to trunk multiple VLANs to a WLC: one for management, and one or more for Wi-Fi clients. These VLANs use one or more DHCP servers for any DHCP clients.

You have twice asked this question in other ways. The answer remains the same, your WLC has nothing to do with DHCP. You need a DHCP controller for the VLAN of the Wi-Fi clients. I don't believe you have the grasp of networking necessary to accomplish this, and I *strongly* suggest you hire a contractor with the expertise to do this.

Comment: Yes  Ron i have asked the similar question before and i got what you were suggesting. Thank you for your suggestion. I would not have come here and asked the questions had i had the cushion of hiring a contractor. Anyway, there was this option called DHCP scope so i thought assigning the pool there could help. I don't think suggesting me to hire a contractor is encouraging words for young and aspiring IT guy like me. After all this is what this website is for, i believe. Sorry if i offended you. Have great time.

Comment: @de.walkar, you didn't offend me, but I don't believe you currently have the skill set to do this. That's not a bad thing, unless you need to get it done, in which case, you either need to acquire the proper skills (this is so broad as to be off topic here), or you need to hire someone (or make friend's with someone who can do it for you) with the skills to do it. Anyone with any experience in networking has been in such a position; it's part of getting to where you aspire to be. Please don't think I am discouraging you, and I may be wrong, but I don't feel you currently have the skills.

Comment: Now that's encouraging Ron....I don't have much friends here as i am new to this place. So i am here at stack exchange to get valuable information and enhance my skills. Especially, i am new to Wireless. I will continue working hard and understanding the basics. Thanks a lot Ron for this platform, seriously, i am getting to learn a lot here.

Comment: Have you looked to see if there is a Cisco User Group anywhere near you? You can meet and make friends with people of all skill levels, and they want to help you succeed.

Comment: I am looking forward to it. As you said, i am trying to make friends with skilled group but i don't know if there are any one from cisco user group anywhere near me. Anyway, thanks for the suggestion.